# Python 3 unable to pickle lambda

Tags: python, lambda, pytorch

I was following a tutorial online about [Deep Learning for Self-Driving Cars](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-self-driving-cars-7f198ef4cfa2) with pytorch. But then I encounter some problem when python trying to pickle lambda.

I've tried to define my own function but then the result is still the same

Below is where I define my dataset for training.

```py
params = {'batch_size': 32, 'shuffle': True, 'num_workers':4}
training_set = Dataset(train_samples, transform=transdorms.Compose([transforms.Lambda(lambda x: (x/255)-0.5)])
training_generator = DataLoader(training_set, **params)
```

Then the problem is at the following code.

```py
for local_batch, (centers, lefts, rights) in enumerate(training generator):
        ... Some code
```

The following error is shown

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle `<function <lambda> at 0x000001B915587948>`: attribute lookup  on **main** failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error :\_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000002F2175B048>: attribute lookup <lambda> on \_\_main\_\_ failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347217/error-pickle-picklingerror-cant-pickle-function-lambda-at-0x0000002f2175b)

Answer (score 0):

Python documentation says that `lambda` functions cannot be pickled.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#id2:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
>   qualified” name reference, not by value. 2 This means that only the
>   function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
>   function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
>   function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be
>   importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
>   the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#id7:

> This is why lambda functions cannot be pickled: all lambda functions
>   share the same name: .

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Guess I just have to define my own transformation class then pass it in.

Comment: @RuiDian you can try to write `def my_lambda(x):  return (x/255)-0.5)` and use it instead of lambda.