# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x0000026D008DFF70>: attribute lookup _lambdifygenerated on __main__ failed

Tags: python, pickle

For some reason I can't save my newly created object with pickle.

This is my Python code:

```py
import pickle
from distutils.log import warn
from ikpy.chain import Chain
import numpy as np
import casadi as cs
from urdf2casadi import urdfparser as u2c
import os

urdf_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "..")) + "/casadi_code/derivative of jacobian/urdf2casadi/examples/urdf/robot_leftarmURDF.urdf"
bb = Chain
my_chain_l = bb.from_urdf_file(urdf_path) 


class ForwardK_InverseK():
    def __init__(self) :
        self.my_chain_l = my_chain_l
    
    def pp(self):
        print("pp")


AA = ForwardK_InverseK()

with open("data.pickle", "rb") as file:
    pickle.dump((AA), file)

with open("data.pickle", "rb") as file:
    aSa= pickle.load(file)
```

After running, it get this error: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x0000026D008DFF70>: attribute lookup _lambdifygenerated on __main__ failed`

So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please format your code into something that's legible

Comment: It's saying that `ikpy` hasn't added pickle support for `Chain`s. Maybe you should just pickle the filename rather than the whole object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error :\_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x0000002F2175B048>: attribute lookup <lambda> on \_\_main\_\_ failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347217/error-pickle-picklingerror-cant-pickle-function-lambda-at-0x0000002f2175b)